# BufferedReader.readLine() gives error java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, tcp

I am trying to code my program so that the buffered reader gets something in readLine() from my tcp client but I get this error as soon as the program executes

```
   Mar 31, 2010 11:03:36 PM deswash.DESWashView$5 run
SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        at deswash.DESWashView$5.run(DESWashView.java:448)
```

the car=in.readLine() in the following code throws the error

```
 public void getCar(){
        Thread gettingCars = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    car = in.readLine();
                    if(!(car.equals(null))){
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(car,";");
                        int carTime = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        finTime.setText(""+((Integer.parseInt(currentTime.getText()))+washTime));
                        currentTime.setText(""+carTime);
                        eventTextArea.append(""+car+"\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DESWashView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        gettingCars.start();
        doOnce=false;
    }
```

Comment: can you please post some of the code that give you this error?

Comment: Please check this link 

http://blogs.sun.com/oleksiys/entry/strange_software_caused_connection_abort

Here one scenario is mentioned like the connection is closed after that some request send to server. because of that when you try to recieve the data you getting this exception

Comment: @sreejith The blog is mistaken. If the peer closes the connection the exception will read 'connection reset by peer'. This is 'software caused connection abort'. Different thing.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> `WSAECONNABORTED (10053)` Software caused connection abort
>
> A connection abort was caused internal to your host machine. The software caused a connection abort because there is no space on the socket's queue and the socket cannot receive further connections.
>
> WinSock description: The error can occur when the local network system aborts a connection. This would occur if WinSock aborts an established connection after data retransmission fails (receiver never acknowledges data sent on a datastream socket).
>
> TCP/IP scenario: A connection will timeout if the local system doesn't receive an (ACK)nowledgement for data sent. It would also timeout if a (FIN)ish TCP packet is not ACK'd (and even if the FIN is ACK'd, it will eventually timeout if a FIN is not returned).

It seems to happen more with WindowsXP and it seems also to be possibly related to Windows firewall settings. In any case the salient point is that the abort has originated inside the local machine.

It's a stupidly worded message.